# アラートのOKをクリック後も、フォームに入力した値を残す方法

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

パスワードが一致しなかった場合にはアラートを表示します。
アラートのOKをクリックすると入力した内容が全て消えてしまうのですが、消えずにそのまま残すにはどうしたらいいのか教えていただきたいです。

ajaxを使うと複雑になるとおもうのですが、どのようにするのか教えて頂きたいです。

**Javascript**

```
function passwordCheckFunction() {
    var loginPass1= document.getElementById("loginPass1").value;
    var loginPass2= document.getElementById("loginPass2").value;

    if(loginPass1 !== loginPass2){
        alert("パスワードが一致していません。")
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <th>パスワード</th>
    <td>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "loginPass1" th:field="*{loginPass}">
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <th>パスワード確認</th>
    <td>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "loginPass2" th:field="*{loginPass}">
    </td>
</tr>
<button type="button" class="passwordCheck" onclick="passwordCheckFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: 「フィールドに入力した」内容が消えてしまう/そのまま残したい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そうです。そのままフィールドに入力した値を残したいです。

Comment: おそらくHTMLではなくて「Thymeleaf」の中身を記述頂いたようですが、それをHTMLで利用できるように変換して試しましたが、HTMLとJSではフィールドが消えることは確認できませんでした。別のところでなにか違うことをやっているか、もしくはテンプレートエンジン側で何かが起きている可能性があります。再現性のとれるHTML＋JSを記載していただけると幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ｊｓは教えていただいたそのまましようしております。、テンプレートはおっしゃる通りthymeleafを使っております。

Comment: 残念ながら編集いただいたコードでも再現性は取れませんでした。質問投稿時の機能である「スニペット」に再現できるコードを貼り付けていただくことは可能ですか？「[質問-回答-スニペットのマークアップ練習場](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331/)」でスニペットのお試しも可能です。